# Exposing Android device as a drive in Windows

Tags: windows, android, file-management

I have an Android 4.x phone, which when connected to a Windows PC, shows up as a device.

Is there any software solution to expose it as a drive instead?

Comment: Is your device rooted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done through any app that allows you to run an FTP server on the Android phone. Two examples are:

- [WebDAV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.theolivetree.webdavserver)
- [FTPServer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=lutey.FTPServer)

Start a server on any of these apps, note the resulting IP address, then type it with `\\` in the `map network drive` window in Windows Explorer after choosing a drive letter:

[image]

Comment: +1 but do they show the whole Android filesystem, including for example Android's `/mnt` folder itself? If not, from what level?

Comment: That very much "depends on". If the app runs with "root privileges" (requiring the device to be "rooted"), the entire file system can be exposed. Otherwise, while it's possible to "start at the base level", not all directories can be shown/accessed. // Btw: for alternatives, be welcome to see my app lists: [Server](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server) has sub-lists for different types. [Various File Servers](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_server_file) is the list you're probably most interested in.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul In addition to what Izzy mentioned, you are also able to specify the level of "home" directory that'll show up in the drive within the settings in FTPServer. It can be anything accessible to the app starting from `/`

Comment: thanks, I was able to get this working with WebDav after a couple attempts. Is there a way to have it connected via USB? (it's going through WIFI at the moment in my setup).

Comment: @Joe I don't think you need an app for that. Just change the settings of the USB connection type from "Media device" into "Mass storage"

Comment: I thought the point of this is that modern android phones do not support mass storage as an option - at least I did not see it on my phone (Android 4.4.2)

Comment: @Joe True. Sadly it only works with rooted devices for newer Android OS using [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mohammadag.samsungusbmassstorageenabler). If yours isn't, an FTP server is the only option I know of